# I'm not getting any output in recursive function

Tags: c, recursion

// this is a recursive function for finding the sum of digits in C language
//I'm not getting any output in my IDE.

```
int dsum(int n)
{
    int a, r;
    r = n % 10;
    a = r + dsum(n / 10);
    return a;
}
int main()
{
    int a;
    a= dsum(12345);
    printf("%d",a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: everytime you enter `dsum()` you keep recursing forever and ever. There is no way for the funtion to terminate. Maybe add `if (n == 0) return 0;` See https://ideone.com/I3bJ9J

Comment: You'll probably get a stack overflow eventually.

Comment: Use hint by pmg. Also init your `a` and make sure that you flush for output. For future questions please study and apply the concept of making a [mre]. The `\`\`` typo indicates that you did not fully get it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A recursion function should always have a base case as a final return, in this case it's when n equals 0, which means all digits were summed (when msb digit is divided by 10 the result is 0).
Then you'll have the return which will call the function with the result of the current lsb digit (or right most digit) + the result of the function with the input of n/10

```
int dsum(int n)
{
    if (n == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    return n % 10 + dsum(n / 10);
}

int main()
{
    int a;
    a = dsum(12345);
    printf("%d",a);
    return 0;
}
```

BTW, I also suggest looking into tail recursion:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call

In this scenario, it might look like that:

```
int dsum_tail_recursion(int n, int sum)
{
    if (n == 0) {
        return sum;
    }
    return dsum_tail_recursion(n/10, n%10 + sum)
}

int main()
{
    int a;
    a = dsum_tail_recursion(12345, 0); // 0 is the sum start value
    printf("%d",a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: thanks!, now its working i cant believe i missed the base part

Comment: Glad I could help!